# jQuery + regular expression to replace href and src values inside textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, expression

I have various textareas:

```
<textarea><a href="/"><img src="/image1.gif" /></a></textarea>
<textarea><a href="/"><img src="/image2.gif" /></a></textarea>
<textarea><a href="/"><img src="/image2.gif" /></a></textarea>
```

And with jQuery I am trying to replace the href and src values (the src initial value must preserve) with regexp converting it into these:

```
<textarea><a href="http://www.sitename.com"><img src="http://www.sitename.com/image1.gif" /></a></textarea> // see how we preserve the original src value by just adding the sitename
<textarea><a href="http://www.sitename.com"><img src="http://www.sitename.com/image2.gif" /></a></textarea>
<textarea><a href="http://www.sitename.com"><img src="http://www.sitename.com/image2.gif" /></a></textarea>
```

I figured out that with the following regexp `(?<=href=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))` and `(?<=src=(\"|'))[^\"']+(?=(\"|'))` I can locate the values but the rest have no idea...

Here is my code so far:

```
$(function(){
        (function(){
            $('textarea').each(function(){
                var obj = $(this);
                obj.text().replace(REGEXP,"http://www.sitename.com/);  //by placing the above regexp the script wont work

                //missing the src part

            });
        })();
    });
```

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the contents of the `textarea` to a jquery collection of DOM elements (assuming you can depend on the HTML being valid).

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
    var $obj = $("<div>" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
    $obj.find("a").attr("href", function (_, href) {
        return "http://www.sitename.com" + href;
    }).find("img").attr("Src", function (_, src) {
        return "http://www.sitename.com" + src;
    });
    $(this).val($obj.html());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RPEzH/2/

Comment: Your code is adding sitename each time i refresh the page producing it like this: <a href="http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/"><img src="http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/http://www.sitename.com/image1.gif"></a>

Comment: I think you are missing the SRC check. If i add it the same way, will it work like this?: if (src.indexOf("http://www.enforex.com") === -1)

Comment: @devjs11 yeah it should; I just used that as an example

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution

```
$('textarea').each(function(){

    // url helper function
    // this function will not prepend if the domain is already present
    var appendDomain = function(url) {
      return url.replace(
        /^(?:http:\/\/www\.sitename\.com)?/,
        'http://www.sitename.com'
      );
    };

    // create an html wrapper
    var html = $('<div></div>');

    // append current textarea contents
    html.append($(this).val());

    // find the A and IMG elems
    var a   = html.find('a'),
        img = a.find('img');

    // set the new href
    a.attr('href', function(idx, href){
        return appendDomain(href)
    });

    // set the new src
    img.attr('src', function(idx, src) {
        return appendDomain(src)
    });

    // set the new html
    $(this).val(html.html());

});
```

[See it working on JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/YfDh6/1/)

Comment: Not sure why you rolled back my initial edit. I was just helping you shortcut some of the attr settings.

Comment: very nice, thank you! But i doubt beetween yours and most voted... seems the same thing

Comment: @devjs11, it's very similar, mine just used a slightly different technique for wrapping the textarea contents in a `DIV`. His answer is also pretty dense whereas mine sacrifices brevity in exchange for legibility and ease of learning.

Comment: @devjs11, per you comments above, I made an edit. Now it will only prepend `http://www.sitename.com` if it's not already there :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex to do that. You just have to concatenate the current url and the website url.

```
$('textarea').each(function(){
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.find('a').attr('href', 'http://www.sitename.com' + obj.find('a').attr('href'));
            obj.find('img').attr('src', 'http://www.sitename.com' + obj.find('img').attr('src'));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

And regex solution isn't too hard, too: :)

```
$(window).load(function() {


   $('textarea').each(function(){

    replaces= 'http://www.sitename.com';    

    text=$(this).text();

new_text=text.replace(/<a href=\"\/">/g,'<a href="'+replaces+'" >');

newest=new_text.replace(/<img src=\"/g,'<img src="'+replaces);

$(this).val(newest);

   })

});
```